# Display privileges and levels on Android app

Tags: feature-request, android-app, privileges

On the current Android App I get notification that new privileges are approaching, but I don't get to view the privileges within the app, nor get to see the privileges ladder.

Could both of these be added to the Android app?

Comment: Side note: this would be nice in the ios app as well